# How to Upload a folder to bitbucket repo using API and CURL

Tags: curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I'm able to upload a file to bitbucket repository but there is any way to upload a folder using CURL and API.

Answer (score 1):

The API is thinly documented, but this is what works for me:

Using cURL:

```
curl --user <username:password> -X POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<workspace_name>/<repository_name>/src -F <local_file_name.ext>=@<destination_filename.ext>
```

For a username of "Foo" and password of "Bar", in my workspace called "widgetcentral", a repository named "testRepo", local filename of "sampleFile.txt" I would do

```
curl --user Foo:Bar -X POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/widgetcentral/testRepo/src -F sampleFile.txt=@sampleFile.txt
```

One caveat, this seems to upload only to master, I can't get it to upload to any branch.

Comment: Can this be used to upload an entire directory?

Comment: no.. curl does not allow that.. you might have to use something like : curl -F {file1,file2,file2 }  - atleast for artifactory this works